# matplotlib.pyplot contourf function introduces holes or gaps when plotting regular data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am trying to plot a 3D dataset using the contourf function in matplotlib.pyplot. All of this is being run inside an iPython notebook. A surface plot of the data looks fine, but the contourf plot has a big hole in it.

A simplified version of the code I am using is:

```
import numpy as np # import modules
import scipy.io as spio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
zMin = 1.2
data = spio.loadmat('./OD_SurfMatFiles/surf_k2_c3.mat')
X = data['xVal']
Y = data['yVal']
Z = data['zVal']
plotX, plotY = numpy.meshgrid(X, Y)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d')
colourLevels = [0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4];
cset = ax.contourf(plotX, plotY, Z, colourLevels, zdir='z',offset=zMin, cmap=cm.autumn)
CB = plt.colorbar(cset, shrink=0.5, extend='both')
```

The result can be seen here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/www.alexbaldwin.org.uk/pynotebooks/OD%2520Appendix%2520HM%2520Noise%2520Aperture%2520SurfBug%2520MWE%25202.ipynb

The data that is being plotted is exported from MATLAB:

```
xVal =

       384   416   448   480   512   544   576   608   640   672

yVal =

    18    19    20    21    22

zVal =

  Columns 1 through 9

    1.1717    1.1421    1.1358    1.2124    1.1721    1.1840    1.1809    1.1399    1.1708
    1.1286    1.2183    1.1654    1.1675    1.1810    1.1745    1.2100    1.2284    1.2096
    1.2132    1.3057    1.2616    1.1742    1.2639    1.2316    1.2039    1.2277    1.2367
    1.2363    1.1987    1.2367    1.2171    1.2718    1.2040    1.2462    1.1802    1.2218
    1.2230    1.2601    1.2411    1.2436    1.2635    1.2197    1.2300    1.2266    1.2368

  Column 10

    1.2357
    1.2039
    1.3010
    1.2273
    1.2336
```

I originally had this problem with matplotlib 1.2. I considered that they may have fixed it in a later version, but even with u'1.4.x' it still occurs.

Comment: Part of the problem is coming in from matplotlib's "pseudo-3D" plotting. Matplotlib isn't meant for 3D plotting, and doesn't actually do 3D rendering.  If a polygon face is determined to be behind another, the entire face is set to be invisible, rather than only occulding part of it.  Short answer, Try settting the surface to be partially transparent (e.g. `alpha=0.5`), or use a 3D plotting library (e.g. Mayavi's `mlab` interface: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html ). Personally, I'd reccomend going with the latter option if you're going to be doing much in 3D.