# Visualization of Bivariate Probability Distribution

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, seaborn, probability-distribution

I need to obtain the 3D plot of the joint probability distribution of two random variables x and y. Whereas this plot can be easily obtained with Mathematica, I wasn't able to find any documentation in Python.

[image]

Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Look at [numpy.histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html). Also, look at [this example from Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) for plotting 3D histograms, although I prefer to visualize such histograms with [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), as a 2D "image".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @AhmedFasih, I agree with you, indeed this [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) provide a neat representation of what I want to do, but it is a matter of orders from high

Comment: You can probably use projections over the original histogram data to get what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26743682/4183191, https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29550378/4183191 etc

Comment: What exactly is the problem with [this approach](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html)?